# Stop any modification on the inodes tables

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have just deleted a file and I would like to recover it. 
I know that the first think to do is to stop any changes in with inodes. How do I do this?

Comment: `mount -o remount,ro _mountpoint_`, will remount the filesystem read-only, but that might not be possible on a running system if the filesystem is on heavy use, and especially if it's the root filesystem, you might have to shut off the system first.  Obviously doing that "normally" will incur heavy disk usage.  Glad I'm not trying to do this :P

Comment: :)  thanks, but the problem is that it is the only partition that I have on this machine, so I can not unmount it. I have seen once long ago a command that tells to the system to stop any modification of the indoes table (trying to buy time :) )

Comment: ooh, this looks like what you're talking about: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.475.4958&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: You can always remount read-only, that's what the kernel does when it detects hardware trouble. Reboot from an USB stick with a SystemRescueCD image or similar, and recover file with debugfs. Or take out the harddisk, connect it to a second PC, and then recover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to prevent inode changes is to mount in read-only or to shut down the system.

Personally, I would either have run a file recovery utility immediately after deleting the file or else I would have shut the computer down and then attempted recovery.

Easiest way to do this would be to reboot into a live CD or USB drive and mount your drive read-only. Another way would be to pull the drive and put it in another computer or in an external enclosure.